# Which Amadeus API service should I use to retrieve passengers who booked flights on a particular date through our travel agency

Tags: rest, amadeus

Which Amadeus API service should I use to retrieve passengers who booked flights on a particular date through our travel agency along with the booking price, route and PNR of the booking.

Answer (score 0):

using Amadeus Self Service APIs is not possible to do. I recommend to contact with Enterprise team to review if exist an Enterprise solutiton for this idea:
https://developers.amadeus.com/support